# Angularjs md-button words capitalize

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I made some md-buttons in this way below, but unfortunately the second word within  tags are not capitalized if there is more than one word.

```
<md-button ui-sref="DMmain">
    <i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i>
    <h3>Device Management</h3>
</md-button>
<md-button ui-sref="ARmain">
    <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i>
    <h3>Access Rules</h3>
</md-button>
<md-button ui-sref="UMmain">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
    <h3>User Management</h3>
</md-button>
<md-button>
    <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-2x"></i>
    <h3>Account Profile</h3>
</md-button>
```

The effect is like this image below,
[image]

`<i class>` is a library called Font Awesome that I used for icons only. Thanks in advance for any ideas how to solve this problem.

**EDITED & SOLVED**: Doing `text-transform: capitalize !important;` for `md-button` does not really work. You have to put class onto those tags you want to edit and add `text-transform: capitalize;` to your class in css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to override the CSS to achieve this, as follows:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial', 'ngAria'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

    });
})();
```

```css
.capitalize-button {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

/* 
OR just override the .md-button class in your css.

.md-button {
  text-transform: capitalize !important;
} 
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.9/angular-material.min.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <md-button ui-sref="DMmain">
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i>
      <h3 class="capitalize-button">device management</h3>
    </md-button>

    <md-button ui-sref="ARmain">
      <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i>
      <h3 class="capitalize-button">access rules</h3>
    </md-button>

    <md-button ui-sref="UMmain">
      <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
      <h3 class="capitalize-button">user management</h3>
    </md-button>

    <md-button>
      <i class="fa fa-file-text fa-2x"></i>
      <h3 class="capitalize-button">account profile</h3>
    </md-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "use strict" will make my Angular app not showing on the webpage, I don't know why... Other than that, everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: **"use strict";**  Defines that JavaScript code should be executed in "strict mode". You can check it here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp, in other words, it's just a good practice..

Comment: "use strict" makes my webpages disappear (gives a whole blank page) if I made any code are not "strict". I guess it is a tool that helps us to write code with high quality.